# Using jQuery to update the st_url attribute of the sharethis chicklet button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharethis

I am dynamically updating the attribute 'st_url' of all of the sharethis spans to the url of a video clicked with jQuery. In firebug you can see it is updating the st_url attribute of my spans, however I the sharethis button is still tied to the initial url. I read I may have to reinit the elements, but I am unsure of the best way to do this? Has anyone done this or have any idea of the best way to re-initialize the buttons with the updated url? Thanks!

Sharethis includes and init:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var switchTo5x=true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({publisher:'xxxx'});
</script>
```

My markup:

```
<span st_url="http://sharethis.com" class='st_stumbleupon' ></span>
<span st_url="example" class='st_facebook' ></span>
<span st_url="example" class='st_twitter' ></span>
<span st_url="example" class='st_email' ></span>
```

My jQuery to update the attr="st_url" when a user clicks on a video:

```
//note: this is triggered by .bind('click')
var youtubeID = $(this).attr('id');
$('#container div > span').each(function(){
    //update sharethis to current video
    $(this).attr('st_url','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + youtubeID);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's no updateEntry call in ShareThis you need to use jQuery's .html() to recreate your  elements inside your container, then repopulate each one using individual calls to stWidget.addEntry against the span's ID.

Comment: Ooooops, Site Not Found.

Please show other ways @vees

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code from my project. Hope, you could use it.

```
// define attributes for buttons
settings.share_buttons = [
    ['facebook','st_facebook_large','Facebook','Share on Facebook'],
    ['twitter','st_twitter_large','Tweet','Share on Twitter'],
    ['pinterest','st_pinterest_large','Pinterest','Share on Pinterest'],
    ['linkedin','st_linkedin_large','LinkedIn','Share on LinkedIn'],
    ['googleplus','st_googleplus_large','Google +','Share on Google +'] 
]; //[service,class,displayText,title]

// all code under could be placed into a function and bind on a click event 
// (don't forget about variable with URL, 'our_link_to_share').

//if block with buttons already exists
if (document.getElementById('share_this_id')){
    $('#share_this_id' > span').each(function(){
     $(this).removeAttr('st_url').attr('st_url',our_link_to_share).empty();
        stWidget.addEntry({
            "service":$(this).prop('service'),
            "element":this,
            "url":$(direct_link).prop('value'),
            "title":$(this).prop('title'),
            "type":"large",
            "text":$(this).prop('displayText'),
            "image":"http://www.softicons.com/download/internet-icons/social-superheros-icons-by-iconshock/png/256/sharethis_hulk.png",
            "summary":"My site"
        });
    });
}// if not, we'll create it
else{
    $('body').append($('<div>').prop('id', share_this_id).prop('class', 'share_this'));
    var share_this = document.getElementById('share_this_id');
    for(i=0; i&ltsettings.share_buttons.length; i++){
        $(share_this).append($('<span>').attr('st_url', our_link_to_share).prop('class', settings.share_buttons[i][1]).prop('displayText', settings.share_buttons[i][2]).prop('title', settings.share_buttons[i][3]).prop('service', settings.share_buttons[i][0]));
    }
}
if (stButtons){stButtons.locateElements();},
```

Comment: thanks ... almost works except for the HULK icon. I want the default icon, but refreshing the widget like this throws saway the default icon ...

Answer (score 1):

I use the following snippet to reinitialize ShareThis buttons after loading in a new page via ajax. Just make sure to add in your publisher key:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js',  
    dataType: 'script',  
    success: function(){  
    stLight.options({  
    publisher: 'xxx',  
    onhover: false  
    });  
    },  
    cache: true  
});
```

I originally found the snippet, at the location I link to below below, after searching for a long time for a good solution. Reposting here because it was buried in a mass of other overly complicated code: http://forums.sharethis.com/topic.php?id=3937#post-84933

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I also ended up rewriting the whole block. I did it like this

```
<div id="share-buttons">
    <button>custom stuff</button>
</div>

<div id="share-template" style="display:none">
    <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
    <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Twitter' st_via="Myself"></span>
    <span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
    <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
</div>
```

everytime the url to share changed:

```
var url=newurl, title = newtitle;
$('#share-buttons > span.st_dynamic').remove();
$('#share-template > span').empty().unbind().removeAttr('st_processed').each(function(){
    $(this).clone().prependTo('#share-buttons')
        .attr('st_url',url)
        .attr('st_title',title)
        .addClass('st_dynamic');
});
if (window.stButtons) stButtons.locateElements();
```

all the empty().unbind.removeCrap() appeared necessary. also necessary to reset the st_title - it was cached somewhere.

YMMV, especially since the buttons.js is external and this undocumented stuff changes :-/